# Minizinc piecewise linear function

Tags: minizinc

I have a cost minimization problem.In the problem we have 3 suppliers. They are S1,S2 & S3, where cost is calculated as  price x Qty purchased.

Price value for 3 suppliers as follows.

```
price=[10,15,20]
```

If I have a decision variable as `array[1..3] of var int:purchase` where I am going to get the answers from optimization problem from which supplier how many units I need to purchase.

Sample code as follows.

```
enum suppliers={s1,s2,s3};
int: len_sup=length(suppliers);
set of int:range_sup=1..len_sup;

array[range_sup] of int:price=[10,15,20];
int:demand=40;

array[range_sup] of int:moq=[5,0,5];
array[range_sup] of int:maxoq=[8,20,30];

array[range_sup] of var 0..100:purchase;

constraint sum(i in range_sup)(
purchase[i])=demand
;

constraint forall(i in range_sup)(
purchase[i]>=moq[i] \/ purchase[i]=0
);

constraint forall(i in range_sup)(
purchase[i] <= maxoq[i]
);

var int:cost;

constraint sum(i in range_sup)(
purchase[i]*price[i])=cost;

solve minimize cost;
```

Now I have a new requirement to embed price discounts for this.This price discount will definitely vary from the qty we purchase.

for this example imagine it is known that from any supplier if we purchase Qty of 1 to 5 then we would get 5% discount (price would decrease from 5%) on the price. If we purchase 6 to 10 we get 10% price discount. If we purchase more than 11 we get 15% price discount.

How do you incorporate this thing to model.Is this using by piecewise linear functions (because it seems like problem becoming non linear)? Can someone show how could this using piecewise linear function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this don't really answer your question, but for some solvers (e.g. Gecode, JaCoP, and OptiMathSAT) you can use a lookup table for this.

You can add a simple discount table:

```
array[1..3,1..3] of float: discount = array2d(1..3,1..3,
[
 1,5,0.05,  % between 1 and 5: 5% discount
 6,10,0.10, % between 6 and 10: 10% discount
 11,1000,0.15, % 11.. 5: 15% discount
]);
```

and change the cost constraint to

```
constraint
cost >= 0 /\
cost =
sum(i in range_sup) (
   purchase[i]*price[i]
    % lookup the discount 
    - purchase[i]*price[i]*sum(r in 1..3) (
          discount[r,3]*(purchase[i] >=  discount[r,1] /\
          purchase[i] <= discount[r,2]
      )
 ;
```

The optimal solution will then be

```
purchase = array1d(1..3, [8, 20, 12]);
cost = 531;
```

As mentioned earlier, this works only for solvers that support var float variables and also the non linear float_times.

**Update**: suresh_chinthy asked about `piecewise_linear`. Here's an example how to use it. Note that it will work with Gecode, JaCoP, OptiMathSAT, but not with linear solvers such as CBC since `piecewise_linear` returns a `var float` which is multiplied with the   decision variable `purchase[i]` (which is `var inte`) and this is not allowed in CBC.

Change the `discount` table from the code above, with these two arrays. Here we assume that it's possible to buy between 0 and 40 items.

```
% the amount of purchase
array[0..40] of float: discount_base = array1d(0..40,[i | i in 0..40]);
% the discounts for each purchase
array[0..40] of float: discount =
   array1d(0..40,
           [0.0, % 0
            0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, % 1-5
            0.10,0.10,0.10,0.10,0.10, % 6-10,
            0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15, % 11-20
            0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15, % 21-30
            0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15, % 31-40                        
            ]);
```

And the `cost` constraint is changed to

```
constraints
  cost > 0 /\
  cost = 
       sum(i in range_sup) (
       purchase[i]*price[i] - purchase[i]*price[i]* piecewise_linear(1.0*purchase[i], discount_base, discount)
  );
```

The result is the same as above:

```
purchase = array1d(1..3, [8, 20, 12]);
cost = 531;
```

Comment: Thanks @hakank for your suggestion,Just need to clarify whether the ....function var float: piecewise_linear(var float: x,
array [int] of float: xi,
array [int] of float: vi) can be applied to this. (Piecewise linear functions as mentioned in the user guide)

Comment: because currently my model only solvable from coin-bc. (Not the above sample code)

Comment: It depends on what you will do with the value returned by `piecewise_linear`. Since it returns a `var float`, CBC will not allow that you multiply another var int/float with it (since CBC don't support `float_times`). But you can use it with addition and subtraction. I'll also update my answer with an example how to use piecewise_linear (still just for Gecode etc).

Comment: thanks for clear explanation.I think I am lack on knowledge on the each solvers limitations and identical features of each solvers.Could you recommend a place where I can learn the solvers comparisons (Which solver is useful in which scenario etc..).And thank you very much for your valuable feedbacks.

Comment: The MiniZinc site mention some of this at https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/solvers.html  but I'm not aware of a more systematic comparison.